# Duplicated question in the Stack Exchange "tagged questions / my tag set"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, tag-filters

The new feature that allows you to view question for all the Stack Exchange<sup>The Real Trademark <sup>TM</sup></sup> website is really nice. The only thing that bugs me is that when you follow multiple tag and question are tagged with more than 1 tag that you follow, they show up more than once with the exact same link to the question.

For example, when I follow the tag `node.js` and `javascript` I get this and  when I remove the tag `node.js`, it only show me the question once.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.